# Azure Toolkit for Eclipse "Sign In" not working

Tags: eclipse, azure

Azure Toolkit for Eclipse: v.3.25.0
Eclipse: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers
JDK: 16

From "Eclipse Marketplace" I installed successfully "Azure Toolkit for Eclipse 3.25.0" package, I restarted Eclipse and when I tried to press the "Sing In" button from Azure it did not work.

The "Sing In" button it's only working from the right corner button, only if I have the "AzureExplorer" open.

After I tried to sing in with my account, I receive on my browser "You have signed in to the Azure Toolkits for IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse application on your device. You may now close this window.", but no reaction from Eclipse, it remains the same: "Azure(Not Signed In)".

Also the "Cancel" button is not working.

I would be grateful if you could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
According to this [post](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-installation.md), the Azure Toolkit for Eclipse requires the following software components:

- A Java Developer Kit (JDK), v1.7 or later.

---

1. You can select Azure Device Login. Type the generated code in the input box to open the webpage. As follows show:
   [image]
2. The tool will check out all your subscription accounts, you can select your subscription at this page.
   [image]
3. Here will show your subscription:
   [image]

Comment: Hi! I did that several time and every time on browser I receive "You have signed in to the Azure Toolkits for IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse application on your device. You may now close this window.", but in Azure Explorer it remain "Not Signed In".

Comment: Hi  @GeorgianaRaluca, Can you show us some screenshots?

Comment: By the way, I am using JDK1.8. Can you change to JDK 1.8 to try again.

Comment: Hi @GeorgianaRaluca I've updated my answer. It seems that your jdk version is too low.

Comment: Hi @JosephXu, after I'll try I'll tell you if it works for me or not. Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: Hi @GeorgianaRaluca Is there any progress on this issue?

Comment: Hi @JosephXu, I tried with jdk-13 version and apparently it's working with this one. Thank you so much for your help.