# Azure sign in does not appear

Tags: eclipse, azure

I installed **Azure** in Eclipse both, on the **Eclipse Marketplace** and on their site with drag and drop, and I still can't access **Azure Sin In** menu by clicking on **Tools-> Azure-> Sign in**.

What should I do to be able to access the sign in window?

Comment: Is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67226755/13979487) helpful for you?

Comment: I tried to reinstall the plugin but it doesn't work to access Azure Device Login either.

Comment: Can you show us some screenshots?